# Display image from local using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to preview image from local drive. Image name is save in the local db. 
Functionality is, first we create a user, upload pic and after we can edit the user. When we edit the user, I am unable to load the same pic which was uploaded previously.

angularjs controller

```
vm.editUser = function(row, $scope, $sce) {
  vm.saveAction = false;
  vm.imageExist = true;
  vm.user = row.entity;
  vm.imagePath = "src/main/webapp/app/img/images/jerry.jpg";
};
```

UI

```
<tr>
   <td>
   <div ng-show="!usrc.saveAction">
   <img alt="" ng-src="{{usrc.imagePath}}" /> 
   </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's unrelated to angular. Try to open this image in new tab before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web server ? If so you should access it like this :

`"localhost:portNumber/yourProjet/img/images/jerry.jpg"`